# In microsoft dynamics crm 4.0 dlg_error.aspx page with customer number as error pops up on clicking on the save button on CASE form for service 

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am trying to customize the 'CASE'  form  for service. Someone else was working on it before me he added a lookup 'contact'  field . we have one live crm system and one test system . Everything is working fine on live system but not on test system. On test system when i click on  'Save' button a pop up coms up with a big red cross sign and displays customer number as error. The address bar of the popup shows that it is the dlg_error.aspx page. i compared it with the live sytem's entity but i cannot find anything wrong.which files/events i need to check . i alredy checked the page onload, onsave events and onchange events of fields.

Can anyone please help me with this problem. so that i can solve this and proceed with my new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

What I would try first is to export the Case entity from the test org (just as a backup), export the Case entity from prod, import prod's version into test, then publish. Does the error still occur?